# How to make a sound of dragon roar?

Tags: sound-design, video-games

I always have been interested how does that sounds of dragon roaring are made in the movies or in the videogames. So, the question, exactly, how? :)

Comment: omg i think i'm in love with this site

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, the best way to do it is to find yourself a wild dragon that hasn't been exposed to humans too much and by tickling it behind its ears you will cause it to roar. You just have to make sure to stay clear of the tail and head though.

And for the real answer: 
Most dragon roars or rather "animal" roars are a combination of different roars, breathing sounds and similar taken from all kinds of animals and layered on top of each other, this is where sound design really becomes an art form and great outlet for creative ideas. As an example I've used swooshes, mechanical grinding sounds, diesel engines and many other non-animal sounds to "enhance" the sound of a roar.

Comment: + Pitch and Formant adjusting and Granular Synthesis to make it evil!

Comment: If you are going to tickle a wild dragon, it is best to remember the Hogwarts moto.  Draco dormiens nunquam titillandus
"Never Tickle a Sleeping Dragon"

Comment: My favourite dragon sound is a pitched down Komodo Dragon.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jgjOdKM190

Answer (score 0):

Hello my friend check this out

:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm disappointed voice acting wasn't a solution

Comment: Yes, my last batch of dragon roars/growls etc. was all voice acting + pitch shifting.

Comment: No need to be disappointed! Obviously it is another possibility and I know a lot of us often even start out with voice as a base when we try to get a certain idea sketched out, definitely adds a special organic touch to any creature sound.

Comment: t's funny reading my old post, I'm such a hypocrite, lol. Most of the music I listen to is very digital. Of course, many of the samples are from acoustic sources, but I really love hearing the new sounds created by synths, lfo's, etc.